# localization for mvc ajax form and partial view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have used resources file to create multi langual mvc3 application. In _viewStart.cshtml I have these two lines which makes it that loclization works for all views except partial views which is rendered from a ajax.form

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(AsoMvcApp.MySession.Current);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(AsoMvcApp.MySession.Current);
```

when I check the CurrentUICulture for a partial view which is rendered from an action which is called from a ajax form it is still default and not chnaged. when I add those to lines of code in the begining of the partial views it works fine. but I don't want to add it to all partial views. it must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it must be a better way.

Yes, instead of putting this code in your `_ViewStart.cshtml` put it in the `Application_AcquireRequestState` method in your `Global.asax`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
No it is not possible for me because I save the cultureinfo in the session and HttpContext.Current.Session is null.

Comment: You are correct, the session is not yet available in the BeginRequest method. Use the `Application_AcquireRequestState` event instead. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I would say it's the same as if it was in `_ViewStart`, it's just that now you have this information everywhere.